# What is the function of "right" in this sentence?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

In the phrase "[action] right from the comfort of your own home", what is the function of the word 'right'?

It sounds normal and cromulent to my native American English speaker ear, but I'm having a hard time defining what purpose it serves in the sentence, and how I can interpret it. I intuitively understand it to mean "Do  [action] easily and comfortably from home", but I don't know what part of the sentence the word "right" serves.

This was sparked by driving behind a truck which used the name of the store to form the phrase "Shop [right] from home".

Comment: "Right" is an adverb and its function is that of modifier - it is modifying  the preposition "from". It occurs mainly with prepositions indicating spatial or temporal relations. Cf. also _They pushed it right under the bed_; _I pushed it right in_, and the like.

Comment: Right means straight (Merriam-Webster), straight from home or right from home, therefore means directly from. As opposed to having to go over to your barn, which would be indirect. (that's a joke).

Comment: What's confusing is that right and wrong can be nouns, verbs, exclamations, adjectives or adverbs, and the adverbs rightly and wrongly exist right alongside right and wrong. In England there is "the divine right of kings to govern wrong;" in the States, rightly or wrongly, we elect a president to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED recognises the use of ***right*** as an adverb, with examples from Saxon England to the present day.

It lists 13 different senses with many sub-senses, arranged in four categories. The one that perhaps suits the example you have chosen is the very first:

Category I *Senses relating to motion or position: straight, directly, immediately.* Sense 1a. *In a direct course or line; straight. In later use chiefly with prepositions and adverbs.*

The most recent example it gives is from 2005: *Apex Sci. Fiction & Horror Digest 23   **She had to run right home after school every day to sit by Little Sister.***